# How to call an asynchronous JavaScript function synchronously?

Tags: javascript, upload, dom-events

I've checked every question related to my problem in Stack Overflow and couldn't find a way to fix it.

What I am trying to do is; User tries to upload images, they get resized in the client-side and then they get uploaded. I've used [Pica library](https://github.com/nodeca/pica). Everything works fine for one file. However, when I changed it to multiple files, I get duplicates of the last image.

What's happening: Loop 1 thru N times -> resizeImg N times

Ideal Solution: Loop 1 -> resizeImg(1) -> Loop 2 -> resizeImg(2)

Any help would be appreciated.

My code is below:

```
function resizeImg(source) {
    img = new Image;
    img.src = source;
    img.onload = function() {
        width = img.naturalWidth;
        height = img.naturalHeight;
        ratio = Math.min(targetWidth / width, targetHeight / height);
        resizer = window.pica();
        canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.canvas.width = width * ratio;
        ctx.canvas.height = height * ratio;
        resizer.resize(img, canvas, {
            quality: 3,
            alpha: true,
            unsharpAmount: 0
        }).then(result => resizer.toBlob(result, 'image/jpeg', 0.90)).then(blob => imgBlobArray.push(blob)).then(function() {
            console.log(i);
            console.log(imgBlobArray);
        });
    };
}
document.getElementById('select').onchange = function(evt) {
    for (i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
        resizeImg(window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[i]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Off the top of my head I wonder if it is because you are not initializing `img` with `var img` at the top there and you're rewriting it with the last image each time. Are you initializing it globally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have a separate binding of `img` for each call of `resizeImg` - you don't have `var` or `const` or `let` in front of the first use of `img`. You're implicitly creating a global variable. So, to the interpreter, it looks something like

```
var img;
function resizeImg(source) {
  img = new Image;
  img.src = source;
  img.onload = function() {
```

`img` is getting continuously *reassigned*. So, after all iterations, `img` will end up being *only* the last `img` created with `resizeImg` - the references to the other `Image`s have been lost.

So, always declare variables explicitly to ensure each call of `resizeImg` has a separate `img` binding. Do the same with all your other variables as well, or they'll be implicitly global.

```
function resizeImg(source) {
    const img = new Image;
    img.src = source;
    img.onload = function() {
        const width = img.naturalWidth;
        const height = img.naturalHeight;
        const ratio = Math.min(targetWidth / width, targetHeight / height);
        const resizer = window.pica();
        const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.canvas.width = width * ratio;
        ctx.canvas.height = height * ratio;
        resizer.resize(img, canvas, {
            quality: 3,
            alpha: true,
            unsharpAmount: 0
        }).then(result => resizer.toBlob(result, 'image/jpeg', 0.90)).then(blob => imgBlobArray.push(blob)).then(function() {
            console.log(i);
            console.log(imgBlobArray);
        });
    };
}
document.getElementById('select').onchange = function(evt) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
        resizeImg(window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[i]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try defining a recursive function like so

```
function resizeImgRec(files, i) {
    if (i >= files.length)
        return;

    ...

    img.onload = function() {
        ...
        resizer.resize(img, canvas, {
            ...
        }).then(result => resizer.toBlob(result, 'image/jpeg', 0.90)).then(blob => imgBlobArray.push(blob)).then(function() {
            console.log(i);
            console.log(imgBlobArray);
            resizeImg(files, i + 1);
        });
    };
}

document.getElementById('select').onchange = function(evt) {
    resizeImgRec(this.files, 0);
}
```

This way the next `resizeImg` will only execute after the last promise is resolved.